# Parsing XML namespaces?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, namespaces

Using JavaScript/Ajax?

I'm trying to extract values from:

```
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:34 am"   sunset="8:38 pm"/>
```

Looking for something like:

```
var response = transport.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("channel");
sunrise = response[0].getElementsByTagName("yweather:astronomy").item(0).Attributes["sunrise"].Value;
```

But nothing works so far. :'( 
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

There is a special version of `getElementsByTagName` for namespaces: [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.getElementsByTagNameNS).

For example:

```
var response = transport.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("channel");
var sunrise = response[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("[Namespace URI]", "astronomy")[0].getAttribute("sunrise");
```

...where `[Namespace URI]` is the URI of the `yweather` namespace.

Comment: @annakata: Out of interest, how can do you do it in IE?

Comment: I think you can just use getElementsByTagName("yweather:astronomy") with IE. Also, Google feeds API has a cross browser implementation. Maybe you can use that, or something like it: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#getElementsByTagNameNS

Comment: In MSXML, you can set the "SelectionNamespaces" property on the XML DOMDocument object, then use the non-standard "selectNodes" (or "selectSingleNode") method with an XPath selector. See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/06/05/msxml4.html for an example.

Comment: You might need to escape the colon "yweather\\:astronomy"