# How to get qualified tag name using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse an XML using DOMParser, I can get element with simple tag names using getElementsByTagName but if I try to get elements with tag name smpte:image the returned array is empty.
Is there a way to escape the colon ? I tried `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('smpte\\:image')` but same result.
Thanks

Comment: See this question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083565/parsing-xml-namespaces).

Comment: getElementByTagNameNS http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/website/documentation-w3cdom-DOMNode.html#DOMNodegetElementsByTagNameNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is a separate entity, not part of the tag name. You can see this by calling `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('image')`, which will return your namespaced tags.

To get only the `image` tags in the `smpte` namespace you should use [getElementsByTagNameNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByTagNameNS):

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(smpteNamespaceUri, 'image');
```

Example:

```
var xml = '<doc xmlns:smpte="http://example.com/xmlns/smpte"><smpte:image></smpte/image></doc>',
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

console.log(doc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://example.com/xmlns/smpte', 'image'));
// -> [smpte:image]

console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName('image'));
// -> [smpte:image]
```

Answer (score 1):

The colon separates the *namespace* from the *tag name*. I.e. `smpte:` is not part of the tag name.
I guess you are looking for [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagNameNS):

```
var ns = '<namespace URI>';
var images = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns, 'image');
```